# What happened to a question?

Tags: support, deleted-questions

This question: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/12692/cooking-makes-my-clothes-smell is now giving a 404 not found error. Was it deleted? Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hey JYelton, I asked the same question in chat a little while ago - it seems the original poster deleted it.  Not sure exactly why.

Edit: after speaking with you in the comments I did a little digging and found that this is, in fact, by design, as per Jeff's answer here:  [Is deleted question page shown as "Page Not Found"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26287/is-deleted-question-page-shown-as-page-not-found)

Comment: It seems odd that a deleted question would present a `404 not found error` instead of some notice that it was deleted. Perhaps that is <status-bydesign>.

Comment: I agree that it's odd, but I believe it's status-bydesign.  Reading the comments on the answer on [this meta question](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/1107/) on Programmers.SE, it says that deleted questions will show a 404, even for the person who originally posted it. Or at least that's how I understand what I'm reading.  "10K users can see their own deleted questions, just as they can see everyone else's, but low-rep users can't. If they try to navigate back to a question they've deleted it will fail with a 404 error."

Comment: Informative and helpful, thank you.

Comment: No sweat - I also learned something new today :)